# How to use python variables in MySQL Insert statement, i am getting a tuple error, Please suggest

Tags: python, mysql

```
import MySQLdb
name="XYZ"
number=(256, 34576312114897154715004917944343995880721156274004613128261928143013598386679L)
db=MySQLdb.Connect("localhost","root","12345","phone")
cursor=db.cursor()
sql= ("""INSERT INTO phonebook(number, Mobile) VALUES(%s,%s)""" , name,number)
cursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()
db.close()
```

"Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % err)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sql` variable is a tuple

```sql
sql= ("""INSERT INTO phonebook(number, Mobile) VALUES(%s,%s)""" , name,number)
```

So when it try to execute, `cursor.execute(sql)` (where `sql` is tuple) it give error *Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type*

Please use string.

```sql
sql = """INSERT INTO phonebook(number, Mobile) VALUES(%s,%s)""" % (name,number)
```